# C2065 'cout': undeclared identifier

Tags: c++, visual-studio, stl, visual-studio-2017, cout

So I'm a complete noob to C++ and I'm trying to make a simple "Hello world" program for an assignment. My code is below:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    cout<<"hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

For some reason, VS2017 is throwing an error at `cout`, saying it's undefined. I've done some reading on old posts about this and added in `#include "stdafx.h` to see if that would solve it as per old advice, but it continues to give me the error. Any ideas?

EDIT:

Again a complete noob but there are multiple version of stdafx.h that come up when I search for it, here's what looks like the "main" one:

```
  // stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently,
// but are changed infrequently

#pragma once

#ifndef STRICT
#define STRICT
#endif

#include "targetver.h"

[!if SERVICE_APP]
#define _ATL_FREE_THREADED
[!else]
#define _ATL_APARTMENT_THREADED
[!endif]

#define _ATL_NO_AUTOMATIC_NAMESPACE

#define _ATL_CSTRING_EXPLICIT_CONSTRUCTORS  // some CString constructors will be explicit

[!if PREVIEW_HANDLER || THUMBNAIL_HANDLER || SEARCH_HANDLER]
#ifdef _MANAGED
#error File type handlers cannot be built as managed assemblies.  Set the Common Language Runtime options to no CLR support in project properties.
#endif

#ifndef _UNICODE
#error File type handlers must be built Unicode.  Set the Character Set option to Unicode in project properties.
#endif

#define SHARED_HANDLERS

[!endif]
[!if SUPPORT_MFC]
#include <afxwin.h>
#include <afxext.h>
#include <afxole.h>
#include <afxodlgs.h>
#include <afxrich.h>
#include <afxhtml.h>
#include <afxcview.h>
#include <afxwinappex.h>
#include <afxframewndex.h>
#include <afxmdiframewndex.h>

#ifndef _AFX_NO_OLE_SUPPORT
#include <afxdisp.h>        // MFC Automation classes
#endif // _AFX_NO_OLE_SUPPORT
[!endif]
[!if SUPPORT_COMPLUS]

#include <comsvcs.h>
[!endif]

#define ATL_NO_ASSERT_ON_DESTROY_NONEXISTENT_WINDOW

#include "resource.h"
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlcom.h>
#include <atlctl.h>
```

Comment: Wierd. Humour me one moment by writing `std::cout`.

Comment: Also tried that, no luck.

Comment: What's in your stdafx.h? Can you fiddle around with the compiler settings (don't use precompiled headers), and drop it?

Comment: What happens if you remove `stdafx`?

Comment: Throws the same error, Sergey.

Comment: You either have a completely broken installation, or you are doing something completely different from what you are telling us. This code should compile without any problem.

Comment: You should try to locate the `stdafx.h` that is installed *on your computer*, and check if the contents are the same as the one you found online. Alternatively, try putting the online one in your code directory, and see if that compiles.

Comment: Yuck. Start again creating a "console application". You seem to be bringing in all sorts of ATL framework stuff.

Comment: Aaand now it works. Thanks!

Comment: I do not think we should pay any heed to stdafx. OP is claiming that removing stdafx results in the same error, so we can just remove it and forget about it.

Comment: @SergeyA: I just tried with a newly created console app in VS2017. It does require the precompiled header `stdafx.h` or it won't compile. But otherwise, all should work. It looks as if the wrong `stdafx.h` was used in the question.

Comment: You should build *without precompiled headers* (a.k.a. `stdafx.h`).  IMHO, they are not worth the hassle when learning simple programs.  When your programs become huge, then consider using precompiled headers.  When you create a project search all the options and uncheck precompiled headers (just say no).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: yes, I see that that is possible (I'm rather a VS newbie -- not the languages, but the IDE). But that option is not set by default (i.e. no precompiled headers).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis -- "not set by default" -- yes, Microsoft teaches bad habits in order to lock people into their tools.

Comment: @PeteBecker: yes, probably for that reason. But they are not the only ones. <g>

Comment: So I see that the OP has put a comment of "Aaand now it works. Thanks!" however I see no explanation as to what was changed or any reason why it should suddenly start working when before it was not.

Comment: It will be helpful, if you right-click on the line of `#include "stdafx.h"` in your project & choose `Open document "stdafx.h"` and provide the real  `stdafx.h` in your question (by edit it).

Answer (score 6):

`error C2065: 'cout': undeclared identifier` is a result of the absence of `#include <iostream>`. The first cause might be `stdafx.h` content. The one you provided, I'm not so sure how it is related to your `main.cpp`/project. Let's start from a fresh project: *...VS2017 IDE: Create new project, ConsoleApplication project-type, & replace the `main()` function with yours.*

A VS2017 IDE (15.8.2) fresh ConsoleApplication project: ConsoleApplication1

```
// ConsoleApplication1.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    cout << "hello world!";
    return 0;
}
```

stdafx.h: *(Generated by the IDE)*

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently
//

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"


// TODO: reference additional headers your program requires here
```

stdafx.cpp: *(Generated by the IDE)*

```
// stdafx.cpp : source file that includes just the standard includes
// ConsoleApplication1.pch will be the pre-compiled header
// stdafx.obj will contain the pre-compiled type information

#include "stdafx.h"

// TODO: reference any additional headers you need in STDAFX.H
// and not in this file
```

targetver.h: *(Generated by the IDE)*

```
#pragma once

// Including SDKDDKVer.h defines the highest available Windows platform.

// If you wish to build your application for a previous Windows platform, include WinSDKVer.h and
// set the _WIN32_WINNT macro to the platform you wish to support before including SDKDDKVer.h.

#include <SDKDDKVer.h>
```

** This code runs perfectly. **

--

*"there are multiple versions of stdafx.h that come up when I search for it"* - What do you mean? In your project? On the internet? You can't just take one `stdafx.h` from the internet. `stdafx.h` content is tailored per project, not universal. What I provided above, for example, is the IDE default new ConsoleApplication project `stdafx.h`. You may add to the file according to your project needs.